# "Restore Windows Key" Define command as keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, spotlight

I don't love windows but I do like the ability to search applications but pressing the windows key.

I do not want a multi key shortcut like cmd + space.  Is there a way to define the command key to bring up spotlight?

Comment: That would disable your ability to use it in any other context.

Comment: @Tetsujim what about control or alt then?  Also the windows key is both a modifier and shortcut key.

Comment: @Tetsujin William is correct about the Windows key - it's both a modifier key and a shortcut key. If pressed alone it'll open/close the Windows Start Menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the left command key as a shorcut using the BetterTouchTool.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) and El Captain.  Just put this in your private.xml.  If you change command+space to open Launchpad it works well also.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Make command key activate spotlight.</name>
    <appendix>(Send an escape key event when escape key is pressed alone.)</appendix>
    <identifier>private.escape_to_control_escape</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyOverlaidModifier__
      <!-- from -->
      KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
      <!-- to -->
      KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
      <!-- alone -->
      KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

This is also interesting for Sierra https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/pull/247

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

I'm not aware of any way this is possible with macOS natively (neither through System Preferences, AppleScript, or an Automator Service) because the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> keyboard shortcut is actually one of the key sequences reserved by macOS.

You *may* find a way to do this with [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) (or for users of Mavericks, Yosemite or El Capitan, [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)), but I've never tried using a modifier key on its own to activate something.

**Long Answer**

According to the [macOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html):

> You should not override the shortcuts in Table 72-3 that are accompanied by the Apple symbol shown here, because macOS uses the shortcut in some way.

And, when referring to Table 72-3, the very first keyboard shortcut is that for showing/hiding Spotlight:

[image]

Also, the [macOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html) state:

> macOS reserves several key combinations for use with localized versions of system software, localized keyboards, keyboard layouts, and input methods.

One of these is the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> keyboard shortcut which is also reserved for international systems to rotate through enabled script systems (also mentioned in Table 72-3 above, but referred to also in Table 72-1). So, as a minimum, the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> keyboard shortcut will need to remain as is.

**The question then becomes whether you can activate Spotlight via another keyboard shortcut, *in addition to* the default shortcut.** This may be possible, particularly with an applescript that is run by an Automator Service (which in turn is activated by a keyboard shortcut). However, this will not be possible with the use of <kbd>command</kbd> (or any other modifier key) on its own, which leaves you with the option of investigating whether [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) (or for users of an earlier macOS, [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)), can do the job.

Comment: Uh you entire answer is centered around cmd space which has nothing to do with my question.  Reread the question I do not want the cmd space for spotlight.  I'm not trying to disable it it's just not useful for me.  Karabiner elements is what you should probably be referencing considering we are on sierra.

Comment: Actually, I feel the second sentence of my _short answer_ and the last paragraph of my _long_ answer address the crux of your question (i.e. the use of a modifier key on its own). As for Karabiner, thanks for the feedback - I initially missed the 'sierra' tag in your question. I've updated my answer to reference both Karabiner and Karabiner Elements. Thanks again for pointing that out. :)

Comment: so I figured out how to do it in El Captain, but not Sierra.  You can check out my answer.  That was the type of answer I was more looking for although I do appreciate your response.

Comment: That's great! :) Hopefully you find a way to get it working in Karabiner Elements.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is trigger the following applescript(El Captain at least) as a service.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252271536

```
tell application "System Events"
    click UI element "Applications" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
end tel
```